# Physics-Electrostatics: Find electric potential on a center of charged rod

Tags: physics

Sorry if off topic, but I have a question in electrostatics. I didn't get any useful answers at physics forums, so if someone could help I will be very thankful.

I need to find electric potential of a uniformly charged rod at a point on a center of a rod if a referent point is at infinity. Rod is charged with 'Q' and has a length of '2a'.
[image]

If we consider left half of a rod of length 'a', than using superposition method on a half rod gives $$dV_{1/2}=\frac{kdQ}{x}$$ where 'x' is a distance between point 'B' and elementary charge 'dQ'. Now $$V_{1/2}=kQ'\int\limits_0^a \frac{1}{x}\mathrm dx$$ where Q' is longitudinal charge density. This integral is undefined. Could someone help?

Thanks for replies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's nothing to do with electronic design.

Comment: Your math is correct. Finally, you get \$V_{1/2}=\infty\$. Keep in mind the potential of a point charge is known as \$V(r)=C\cdot\frac{1}{r}\$ , i.e. if you move towards the charge (\$r \to 0\$), the potential rises to infinity.

Comment: @sweber What about undefined integral?

Comment: Just calculate the integral. It is \$\int_0^a\frac{1}{x}dx=\ln(a)-\ln(0)\$. And \$-\ln(0)=+\infty\$. (lacking all that limes stuff)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, as now we have another answer, I'll add my comment as answer, too:

The math is correct, if the integral is calculated, one gets
$$V_{1/2}=kQ'\int_0^a\frac{1}{x}\,dx=kQ'(\ln(a)\underbrace{-\ln(0)}_{=+\infty})=+\infty$$

If this looks odd, keep in mind the well known potential of a point charge:

$$V(r)=\frac{Q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{1}{r}$$

For \$r\to0\$, this also rises to \$+\infty\$ .

---

About @Andy aka's answer:

> Capacitance is zero because gap is infinite therefore V is infinite.

While it sounds elegant, it's in general wrong.

I guess this arises from the formula 
$$C=\varepsilon_0\frac{A}{d}$$ 
for the capacitance of a parallel-plate capacitor. Indeed, when d becomes infinite, C becomes zero. But this formula is only valid for an ideal capacitor, where d is not too large, compared to the size of the plates.

If the distance is large, the plates do not behave like an ideal parallel plate capacitor any more, the field looks more like that of two charges spheres. And the capacitance of two spheres of radius R and distance D is:

$$C=2\pi\varepsilon_0\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{D-R}}\right)\quad\xrightarrow{D\ \to\ \infty}\quad C=2\pi\varepsilon_0 R$$

If the spheres have the same origin but different radii \$R_{inner}\$ and \$R_{outer}\$:

$$C=4\pi\epsilon_0 \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_{outer}}-\frac{1}{R_{inner}} } \quad\xrightarrow{R_{outer}\ \to\ \infty}\quad C=4\pi\epsilon_0 R_{inner}$$

So, just having an infinite distance does not lead to a capacitance of zero. (This effect is calles *self capacitance*, by the way)

For the math, see below.

---

It is interesting that a point charge has an infinite potential, and a one-dimensional charge distribution as in this question also has an infinite potential. Thinking about this, I came to the conclusion, that **a charge distribution without volume has an infinite potential**.

The reason for this can be understood from Maxwell's first equation (or the Gauß-equation):

$$\int_A\vec{E}\, d\vec{A}=\varepsilon_0\int_V\rho\, d\vec{V}$$

If we have a look at a charged point / line / plane, we can always put a closed surface around it, such that the charge is fully enclosed  and the electric field has the same strength everywhere (implies that E is perpendicular on surface, as it's also conservative). Then, the equation becomes as simple as:

$$E\cdot A=\varepsilon_0\cdot Q$$

Now, we can choose a smaller and smaller surface, like the shells of an onion. A goes against zero, and because Q is constant, E has to raise against infinity. And since potential is the integral of the E-field (along a path), the potential also raises to infinity.

*If* the charge distribution has a volume, the enclosed charge is not constant. For example, a solid, homogeneous charged sphere of radius R has the potential

$$V(r)=\begin{cases}4\pi\varepsilon_0\cdot\frac{r}{R^2}&\text{for}& r\le R \\ 4\pi\varepsilon_0\cdot r&\text{for} &r \ge R\end{cases}$$

---

### About the math:

The potential field of a charges sphere is that of a point charge in its center, i.e. \$V(r)=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{Q}{r}\$

**Same sized spheres:**

For the two same-sized spheres with opposite charge, the potential field is
$$V_{tot}(r)=V(r)-V(|D-r|)=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\left(\frac{Q}{r}-\frac{Q}{|D-r|}\right)$$

Now, the spheres have radius R, so the potential difference is
$$U=\Delta V_{tot}=V_{tot}(D-R)-V_{tot}(R)=...=\frac{2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\left(\frac{Q}{R}-\frac{Q}{D-R}\right)$$

Now, it's just
$$C=\frac{Q}{U}=2\pi\varepsilon_0\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{D-R}}\right)$$

**Spheres with same center:**

$$V_{inner}(r)=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{Q}{r} \quad\text{for}\quad r\ge R_{inner}$$

$$V_{outer}(r)=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{-Q}{r} \quad\text{for}\quad r\ge R_{outer}$$

Outside the outer sphere, the field cancel each other. The potential at the outer sphere is generated by the inner sphere only. So, the potential difference is

$$U=V_{inner}(R_{inner})-V_{inner}(R_{outer})$$

and

$$C=\frac{Q}{U}=4\pi\varepsilon_0\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_{outer}}-\frac{1}R_{inner}}\right)$$

Comment: I have one question about potential in this case. What happens with the other part, I mean, you just integrate from 0 to a and get +∞, but what about -a to 0 part?

Answer (score -1):

Q = CV where Q is charge, C is capacitance and V is voltage.

Capacitance is zero because gap is infinite therefore V is infinite.

Comment: Sorry, this sounds good, but it's not true. See my answer.

Comment: @sweber are you saying the capacitance is not zero or the reference point is not at infinity because that's what you appear to be saying.

Comment: Thinking about this more, it's none of these. Finally, if the charge distribution has a volume, this volume will have a specific potential. If it has no volume, like a point / line / plane, the potential is infinity.

Comment: @sweber I think you need to be clear about this and be seen to be clear about this. At the moment, I have received a down-vote from you and you have made an answer that you appear to refuting ("Thinking about this more, it's none of these"). I don't think anyone reading these answers will understand what is and what isn't valid.

Comment: Well, the point is that your answer is not consistent, because a sphere definitively has a capacity, as a certain charge leads to a certain potential. That's why it's wrong. However, it seems bodies with volume have a potential, while those without have an infinite potential. I will think about it and add it to my answer soon.

Comment: @sweber the reference point is at infinite and this makes the capacitance zero and that makes the voltage infinite. BTW I don't mind you doing a load of maths and making you answer good BUT you should state why my answer is wrong before down-voting. It's not enough to say "it's not true" then do a pile of math that comes up with the same conclusion as me.

Comment: Andy, you are simply wrong about the capacitance. Putting the reference at infinity does *not* reduce the capacitance to zero. Consider the [capacitance between two concentric spheres](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capsph.html), then let the radius of the outer sphere grow to infinitiy. You'll still have a definite, nonzero value of capacitance that depends on the radius of the inner sphere. Remember, infinity is both infinitely far away, but also infinitely large!

Comment: @dave if the correct answer is infinity and there is finite charge either q doesn't equal Cv or capacitance is zero. Also the question is about a rod and not an infinitely sized sphere or maybe I've misread the question. Anyway I deleted my answer, had a soak in the tub and came to the conclusion your comment was irrelevant.

Comment: You're making less and less sense, the more you say. Maybe you need another soaking. :-) I'm saying that both the charge and the capacitance are finite, so q=CV is not violated in any way. The difference between a rod and a sphere, when considered from a relatively large distance, is infinitesimal. But you can do the same thought experiment with a rod and a cylinder.

Comment: I've extended my answer, I hope, it's more clear now. I guess you are bound too much to the parallel-plate capacitor, where your argument is correct, but which does not work for large distances.